# Chain link AggregatorV2V3Interface Interface error?

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity, chainlink, brownie

I'm following a Solidity tutorial that implements Chain Link's AggregatorV2V3Interface. An error is popping on VSCode 2 while compiling the code with the `brownie compile` command

Here is the error :
[image: Compilation Error]

I'm very new to Solidity and still trying to figure out how that works.

Comment: Can you add more info, like snippet of your brownie project?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You encountered to "Interfaces cannot inherit" error in Solidity. Just increase solc compiler version to 0.6 or later and it should compile. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71258898/compiling-aggregatorv2v3interface-leads-to-typeerror-interfaces-cannot-inherit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the VSCode compiler to `v0.6.6+`
and setting FundMe.sol solidity version to `pragma solidity ^0.6.6;`
is what worked for me